# Removing racket's default reader procedure from the readtable for the character |

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a racket reader extension procedure that disables the special treatment of the pipe character `|`.

I have two files: `mylang/lang/reader.rkt` to implement the lang reader and `mylang/testing.rkt` to try it out. I've run `raco pkg install --link` to install the lang.

Here is `reader.rkt`:

```
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
racket
#:read my-read
#:read-syntax my-read-syntax

(define (parse-pipe char in srcloc src linum colnum)
  #'\|)

(define my-readtable
  (make-readtable #f #\| 'terminating-macro parse-pipe))

(define (my-read-syntax src in)
  (parameterize ((current-readtable my-readtable))
    (read-syntax src in)))

(define (my-read in)
  (syntax->datum
   (my-read-syntax #f in)))
```

With `testing.rkt` like this:

```
#lang mylang
(define | 3)
(+ 3 2)
```

runs and produces 5 as expected. But this next one doesn't:

```
#lang mylang
(define |+ 3)
(+ |+ 2)
```

complaining that `define: bad syntax (multiple expressions after identifier) in: (define \| + 3)` which is reasonable since `parse-pipe` produces a syntax object, not a string, so it terminates the reading of the symbol prematurely.

One thing I can do is keep reading until the end of the symbol, but that is hackish at best because I would be reimplementing symbol parsing and it wouldn't fix the case that the symbol has the pipe char in the middle, or if | is inside a string, etc.

What I would like to do is remove the default reader procedure for | from the readtable, but I don't know how/if it can be done.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I've found a way. The documentation for [`make-readtable`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-readtable%29%29) says:

> char like-char readtable — causes char to be parsed in the same way
>   that like-char is parsed in readtable, where readtable can be #f to
>   indicate the default readtable.

so I can make the reader read `|` like a normal character like `a` with:

```
(define my-readtable
  (make-readtable #f #\| #\a #f))
```

And it works

```
(define hawdy|+ "hello")    
(string-append hawdy|+ "|world")
; => "hello|world"
```

Comment: I +1'd your answer in that it works, but I can't imagine why you'd want to do such a thing (unless you're implementing a reader for a custom, non-Scheme language). In Scheme, using `|` in a symbol is a way to "quote" a symbol so that it can contain arbitrary characters (e.g., `|foo bar|` is read in as the symbol corresponding to `(string->symbol "foo bar")`); by redefining `|`, you take away the ability read in symbols with arbitrary characters.

Comment: It's for a custom lang. I'm more than happy to take racket the way it is ;).